# labview find terminal grayed out

Tags: labview

I am working on some inherited code and I ran across something I've not seen in LabVIEW before...see attached screenshot.  Notice when I right-click on the property node and try to find the Terminal...Terminal is grayed out.  When I find the Control, it takes me to a blank spot on the front panel that has absolutely no controls (I've ensured that the Control has Visible=True by programmatically setting and verifying that property).  I've never seen a Control without a Terminal...what's up?  Using LabVIEW 2012.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

After quite a bit of digging, I found the answer:
It turns out that the Property Node is pointing (linked) to a control which is buried inside a cluster.
The lesson here is: if Find >> Terminal is grayed out, it's possible (likely) that the control to which the Property Node is linked is inside a cluster.  I re-created the scenario with this mini-example:
[image]

[image]

Finally, I couldn't find the front panel control at the onset because it had its Visible attribute set to false *inside the cluster* (the cluster was visible, but not the element within the cluster) and it was physically placed far away from the other controls within the cluster, AND it was placed on a hidden Tab page.